# make popup window centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm popping up a window for facebook authentication and I would like the contents of that page to be centered in the popup window. I am *NOT* asking for how to center the popup window on the screen. I am asking how to center the page in the popup window. Javascript is ok.

```
<a href="/auth/facebook" id="facebook_button" data-width="800" data-height="400">

<script>
$("#facebook_button").click(ask_for_facebook_auth);

function popupCenter(url, width, height, name) {
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(width/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(height/2);
    return window.open(url, name, "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width="+width+",height="+height+",toolbar=no,left="+left+",top="+top);
}

function ask_for_facebook_auth(e){
    popupCenter($(this).attr("href"), $(this).attr("data-width"), $(this).attr("data-height"), "authPopup");
    e.stopPropagation(); return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: How about share some of the markup involved in the popup window so we don't have to guess at what you have.

Comment: Sometimes people are just lazy. Good questions are needed for good answers...

Comment: Sorry about that, I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a general solution to the popup centering, but it solved my issue with the facbeook auth dialog. You have to put

```
config.omniauth :facebook, APP_ID, APP_SECRET, { :display => 'popup' }
```

in your initializers/omniauth so that facebook will generate a centered page that looks nice in a popup.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `window.scrollTo()` method to center the viewport at half the body width/height minus half the window innerWidth/innerHeight respectively. This should accomplish what you're after:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var w = window.innerWidth * 0.5;
    var h = window.innerHeight * 0.5;
    var x = document.body.clientWidth * 0.5 - w;
    var y = document.body.clientHeight * 0.5 - h;
    window.scrollTo(x,y);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to call this from the parent window? I'm not sure how to run javascript on the child window since it's facebook's app permissions page.

Comment: unfortunately, if you don't have editing access to a child page on a different domain, you won't be able to determine the width/height of the child, and therefore won't be able to center the parent window on its contents. However, Facebook may support certain querystring variables that define the width and height of its pages loaded from a foreign domain, at which point, you could use `popupName.scrollTo()` to scroll your popup window given the width/height you defined.

Comment: Hmm I tried w=window.open(...); w.scrollTo(300,10) but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: yeah, you may be looking at a same-origin restriction here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to center your popup.

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
            this.css("position","absolute");
            this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
            this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
            return this;
        }
```

If you want to center div with id **simplemodal-container** then use

```
   $('#simplemodal-container').center();
```